# Swift generate random number without arc4random

Tags: linux, swift, swift3, openwhisk

I want to generate a random number in Swift within a function deployed to OpenWhisk on IBM Bluemix.

Because it's a Linux runtime, I can't use `arc4random_uniform()`. I also don't want to use `drand48()` because it doesn't give me a truly random number (psuedo-random sequence).

Still, so far I've tried...

```
let answer = drand48() * 10000
```

...which yields 3.90798504668055e-10

Any ideas?

Comment: rand() should do it take a look at the following example https://github.com/SwiftOnTheServer/DrinkChooser/blob/master/actions/_common.swift#L8